# ClassCastException in a TreeMap

Tags: java, android

i always get a ClassCastException. I also want to sort the Treemap by the key(pizza.title alphabetical)

Code:

```
public class Pizza implements Comparable<Pizza> {

    public String title;
    public int rate;
    public String date;
    public Bitmap picture;
    public int id;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pizza another) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.title.compareTo(another.title);
    }

}
```

Calling:

```
for (Pizza pizza : list) {

            if(map.containsKey(pizza))
            {

                int i = map.get(pizza.title);
                map.remove(pizza.title);

                map.put(pizza, i++);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(pizza, 1);
            }
          }
```

Error:

```
10-04 08:27:19.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(722): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.korn.pizzacounter.Pizza
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be inconsistent in what you use as the key of your `TreeMap`:

You call `containsKey` with a `Pizza` object, but call `get` and `remove` with a `String`.

*All* keys in a `TreeMap` must be comparable with each other. Since your `Pizza` class is not `Comparable<String>` this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

> map.get(pizza.title);

I guess that your map declaration would be
`Map<String,Integer>`.

so use `pizza.title` as key in methods like `Map#put` and `Map#containsKey`.

Answer (score 1):

A map is from keys to values

Looking at your code, your map is from Pizza's to integers (based on the fact that you do `map.put(pizza.title)`)

When you do `get`, you need to provide a pizza to get an `int`, but you are giving `pizza.title` and that's where you get the class cast exception.

You can either give it a `pizza`, or change the type of the map to string to int (e.g. `Map<String,Integer>`)